# Laravel 5 REST API validation

Tags: php, validation, api, rest, laravel-5

I'm quite new to both RESTful API's and Laravel 5, so excuse me for any dumb questions. :-)

What's the best way to validate API requests (POST/PUT) in Laravel 5? I've learned about [Form Request Validation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#form-request-validation), but that seems targeted towards forms. Would it make any sense to use this for a HTTP REST API as well? Is there a better alternative?

Also, how would one go about validating query strings in GET requests? Is that something to handle in the controller itself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best option is to use the Form Request Validation. The word "form" in the title is misleading - as it is really the ability to handle validation on *any* request - regardless of the source.

You can handle GET requests inside the Request validator - so that all your validation is in one single location.